# When calling the class that extends AsyncTask the parameter doesnt seem to receive the sent String

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I tried to explain my problem as best as I could so sorry if it didn't make sense.
The problem I'm having is when I call the asyncTask class in the `onCreate` method the String doesn't seem to get passed to `doInBackground`.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.Timer;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

String question;
TextView price;
Document document;
TextView article;
private Element overview;
EditText respText;
TextView text;
TextView ans;
String siteUrl;

private class ParseURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

     @Override
     protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
         StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
         try {
             Log.d("JSwa", "Connecting to ["+strings[0]+"]");
             Document doc  = Jsoup.connect(strings[0]).get();
             Log.d("JSwa", "Connected to ["+strings[0]+"]");
              //Get document (HTML page) title
             String title = doc.title();
             Log.d("JSwA", "Title ["+title+"]");
             buffer.append("Title: " + title + "\r\n");

             // Get meta info
             Elements metaElems = doc.select("meta");
             buffer.append("META DATA\r\n");
             for (Element metaElem : metaElems) {
                 String name = metaElem.attr("name");
                 String content = metaElem.attr("content");
                 buffer.append("name ["+name+"] - content ["+content+"] \r\n");
             }

             Elements topicList = doc.select("h2.topic");
             buffer.append("Topic list\r\n");
             for (Element topic : topicList) {
                 String data = topic.text();

                 buffer.append("Data ["+data+"] \r\n");
             }

         }
         catch(Throwable t) {
             t.printStackTrace();
         }

         return buffer.toString();
     }



     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
         super.onPostExecute(s);
         ans.setText(s);
     }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText edtUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtURL);
    Button btnGo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGo);
    //respText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtResp);
    ans = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    siteUrl = edtUrl.getText().toString();

    btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // String siteUrl = edtUrl.getText().toString();
            ( new ParseURL() ).execute(new String[]{siteUrl});
        }
    });
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: do you got any error?

Comment: Simply pass url as String instead String Array like : ( new ParseURL() ).execute(siteUrl);

Comment: i tried that haresh and it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

Get text from `EditText` on click of button instead of inside `onCreate` method:

```
btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       siteUrl = edtUrl.getText().toString(); 
       new ParseURL().execute(siteUrl);
    }
});
```

Comment: @kiwi: are you getting `Log.d("JSwa", "Connecting to ["+strings[0]+"]");` log in logcat?

Comment: yes i am but the site url doesnt show up it just shows: Connection to []

Comment: @kiwi: probably `EditText` is empty. try to put log on button click then check EditText text is same as  enter by user in EditText.

Comment: sorry im a bit confused, how do i do that exactly?  EDIT: oh wait, i get what your saying, ill get on it.

Comment: @kiwi: put `Log.d("JSwa", "text from user:"+siteUrl);` inside onClick method of button after `siteUrl = edtUrl.getText().toString(); ` line

Comment: i got this:    12-24 00:12:07.495: D/JSwa(1536): text from user:http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/04/parsing-html-in-android-with-jsoup.html?m=1

Comment: @kiwi: what you are entering in EditText?

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ i tried it and it still didnt work.

Comment: Make your edittext variable global and you have a global string for url so make your asynctask fully void and use that global variable and get the text from edittext in that global variable inside the click listener. Do all this